# extract doc file from WYSIWYG

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, ckeditor, wysiwyg, blogger

Last week while i was working on WYSIWYG - cKeditor. a question came in my mind. Is there any way to extract or pull out the content of doc or docx file into the blogger or wordpress text area. For instance, we need not to select and copy the text or images from doc(x) file. All we need to do is hand over the file to WYSIWYG and content of doc(x) file is pasted in the post.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks
Fawaz

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Or alternatively, see [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/docx-to-html-free/).

> This plugin will process an uploaded
>   .docx file, extracting all the content
>   as a post.

---

I *think* you can use [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) to extract the contents of .docx files.

(I should probably mention that .docx files are just .zip files with a specific structure; [Open Office XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML))

However, it seems to be more dedicated to writing .docx files instead of reading.

There is class `PHPWord_Template` containing this in the `__construct`:

```
$this->_objZip = new ZipArchive();
$this->_objZip->open($this->_tempFileName);

$this->_documentXML = $this->_objZip->getFromName('word/document.xml');
```

Which returns an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="005B1098" w:rsidRDefault="005B1098"/>
    <w:p w:rsidR="005B1098" w:rsidRDefault="005B1098">
      ...
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="00F15611">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri"/>
          <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">The following table contains a few values that can be edited by the PHPWord_Template class.</w:t>
      </w:r>
      ...
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Which does have the text of the document in it.

It looks like it will be a lot of work using this method if you want to carry over all the formatting. A lot more work than copying and pasting to a textfield.

Comment: No, I haven't, besides looking at the PHPWord source and copying some of the `word/document.xml` by opening the .docx in 7zip.